# TYPO3 DBAL Querybuilder: Cross-database join

Tags: php, typo3, dbal

I want to write a select query to an existing database structure:

```
    private function select(): QueryBuilder
    {
        return ($queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable('deployment'))
            ->select('deployment.*', 'address.*', 'lpt_address.*')
            ->from('deployment')
            ->leftJoin(
                'deployment',
                'address',
                'address',
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('address.id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('deployment.address'))
            )
            ->leftJoin(
                'deployment',
                'address',
                'lpt_address',
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('lpt_address.id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('deployment.lpt_address'))
            );
    }
```

The problem is, that the tables `deployment` and `address` are in different databases.
How can I tell DBAL that `address` is in database `mdb` rather than `hwdb`?

Comment: Did you try https://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/cross-database-joins.html?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for the link. I'll look into it.

Comment: The problem is, that there is no `config.php` for doctrine in TYPO3. Nor is there a `schema.yml`.

Comment: That's not the important part, the important part is specifying the full path like `database.table` when working with table names. Can you give this a try?